# Python - TypeError not all arguments converted duting string formation

Tags: python

I have a script that will accept a random number from a server and then it will tell me if its even or odd, however when I run it I get an error

> TypeError not all arguments converted during string formation

Here is the full error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "client.py", line 18, in 
> if (RNUM % 2) == 0:
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Here is the code:

```
from socket import *

s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("localhost",6000))
r=s.recv(1024)
clientname = "Edward"
print("This is " + clientname + "\'s client")
while(True):
    a=int(input(r))
    if(a >= 1) and (a <=20):

        s.send(bytes(str(a), 'utf8'))
        rnum=s.recv(1024)
        #mat=s.recv(1024)
        RNUM=rnum.decode('utf8')
        #MAT=mat.decode('utf8')
        print("Random Number From Server:",RNUM)
        if (RNUM % 2) == 0:
            print("{0} is Even number".format(RNUM))
        else:
            print("{0} is Odd number".format(RNUM))
        
        #print("Random Number + Number given = ", MAT)
    else:
        print("Invalid Integer, try again")
```

Comment: `RNUM` is a string. `RNUM % 2` doesn't do what you think it would do because of that.

Comment: how can I convert it to an `int`

Comment: The same way you made `a` an `int`.

Comment: Please create a [mre] for this question. This problem can be reproduced in 1 or 2 lines, no need to post your full code.

Answer (score 0):

The variable RNUM is a string. To convert it to an integer, call `int(RNUM)`.